# Adding WatchKit cause Linker error - entry point (_main) undefined for arch arm64

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I get this linker error for the WatchKit Extension target after adding watch kit to an existing iOS project. 
I've not really any ideas where to start in the hunt for the solution to this problem, and can't see any similar threads like it in the forums.
My iOS app is a typical ObjC app running on iPhone6+ (for debug).
The target architecture is "standard architectures (armv7, arm64)
Any ideas??  I am at a loss.
Thanks
Rob.

Comment: If I remove arm64 from the valid architecture list, then the error now refers to amrv7 so how do I set the entry point for the watch kit extension target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following tech note hidden in the bowels of the apple website that may help others that have this issue. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2410/_index.html

I also had to add the WatchKit framework to the “Link with Binaries” section of the Build Phases for the WatchKit extension target.